# Having issue parsing xml with linq to xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, linq-to-xml

I am having a problem parsing xml that I receive from Web Service.

The xml looks very simple:

```
<Result xsi:schemaLocation="urn:yahoo:developer http://developer.yahooapis.com/TimeService/V1/GetTimeResponse.xsd" type="web"><Timestamp>1320677359</Timestamp></Result>
```

But when I try to parse it with following code I am getting no return results.

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://developer.yahooapis.com/TimeService/V1/getTime?appid=StackSolution");           

            var datestamp = from ds in doc.Descendants("Result")
                            select new { currentstamp = ds.Element("Timestamp").Value };
```

Is there a solution or way to parse it?

Thanks you in advance

Comment: Not used that too much, can you include a sample of what the XML looks like?

Comment: Yes I did, in the original message the first line that wrapped in code tags is the actual XML.

Comment: Oh crap, I should scroll over :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple issues: First, the Result node isn't a descendant. It's the root. Second, you ran into the most common issue when using LINQ to XML - you forgot the namespace. The following should give you what you need:

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load("http://developer.yahooapis.com/TimeService/V1/getTime?appid=StackSolution");            
XNamespace ns = "urn:yahoo:developer";
var datestamp = from ds in doc.DescendantsAndSelf(ns + "Result") 
                select new { currentstamp = ds.Element(ns + "Timestamp").Value };
```

Note, this produces an IEnumerable. If you only want the datestamp, consider using FirstOrDefault instead. You may be able to make this simpler by just doing the following:

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load("http://developer.yahooapis.com/TimeService/V1/getTime?appid=StackSolution");            
XNamespace ns = "urn:yahoo:developer";
var datestamp = doc.Element(ns + "Timestamp").Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

This method avoids the namespace issue using [LocalName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.localname%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (unqualified identifier).

```
var datestamp = doc.Root.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.Equals("Timestamp")).FirstOrDefault().FirstNode.ToString()
```